# PHP Session increase expiry time

Tags: php, session

I just want to extend the php session time in my project. From some documentation i found this code:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2*60*60); //2 hours
```

By default , i think its 30 minutes. But I need to increase this. So for testing I set this time for just 2 minutes and tried my code. I waited for 2 minutes, but i didn't expires.

I want my session for more than 5 hours. But my code is not working. I am using this `ini_set` inside my php file rather than in `php_ini`

Answer (score 3):

// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 5 hour

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 18000);
```

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 5 hour

```
session_set_cookie_params(18000);

session_start(); // ready to go!
```

**THEN**

```
$now = time();
if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after']) {
    // this session has worn out its welcome; kill it and start a brand new one
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}

// either new or old, it should live at most for another hour
$_SESSION['discard_after'] = $now + 18000;
```